# trouble displaying results of union select statement

Tags: php, mysql, union

The following query works, but for some reason the first select statement is the only URL being displayed. Items from other tables are displayed, however, their URL is wrong.

```
$sql = "(SELECT postsID as postsID, postsSubject AS postsSubject, postsTimestamp AS timestamp
                FROM   posts
                WHERE  postsCategory = '$id')
            UNION 
                (SELECT eventID as eventID, eventTitle as eventTitle, eventsTimestamp as timestamp
                FROM   events
                WHERE  eventLocation = '$id')
            ORDER BY timestamp DESC";
```

The information is being correctly displayed from both the events and posts table, but the results are appearing to ONLY come from the posts table.

For example, say I have the following info

```
postsID |  postsSubject |  postsTimestamp
  1            post             123

eventID |  eventTitle   | eventsTimestamp
  2           event            456
```

I have the following to display my results

```
   while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    ?>
        <tr><td><? echo '<a href="viewevent.php?eventID=' . $row['eventID'] . '">' . $row['eventTitle'] . '</a>' ; ?></td>
        <tr><td><? echo '<a href="viewpost.php?postID=' . $row['postsID'] . '">' . $row['postsSubject'] . '</a>' ; ?></td>
    <?  
        if(preg_match('/[0-9]/',$row['timestamp'])){        
            list($yyyy,$dd,$mm) = explode('-',$row['timestamp']);
                    $newDate = $dd."-".$mm."-".$yyyy;
            }
        ?>
            <td><center><? echo $newDate; ?></center></td></tr>
        <?
        }
        echo '</table>';
}
```

The output appears to be correct

```
post   123
event  456
```

However, both results link to the following (respectively)

```
viewpost.php?id = 1
viewpost.php?id = 2  //this should be viewevent.php
```

Comment: add the schema of your tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sql as below:

```
$sql = "(SELECT postsID as ids, postsSubject AS description, postsTimestamp AS timestamp,'p' as status
                FROM   posts
                WHERE  postsCategory = '$id')
            UNION 
                (SELECT eventID as ids, eventTitle as description, eventsTimestamp as timestamp, 'e' as status
                FROM   events
                WHERE  eventLocation = '$id')
            ORDER BY timestamp DESC";
```

when retrieving data,

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
     if ($row['status']=="e"){
    ?>
        <tr><td><? echo '<a href="viewevent.php?eventID=' . $row['ids'] . '">' . $row['description'] . '</a>' ; ?></td>
<? }else{?>
        <tr><td><? echo '<a href="viewpost.php?postID=' . $row['ids'] . '">' . $row['description'] . '</a>' ; ?></td>
<? } ?>
    <?  
        if(preg_match('/[0-9]/',$row['timestamp'])){        
            list($yyyy,$dd,$mm) = explode('-',$row['timestamp']);
                    $newDate = $dd."-".$mm."-".$yyyy;
            }
        ?>
            <td><center><? echo $newDate; ?></center></td></tr>
        <?
        }
        echo '</table>';
}
```

Comment: Only the values from my posts table are showing. However, when I select only the events (removing the posts portion of the query) the events are displayed.

Comment: when execute the query alone in the mysql itself, the returned result is accurate?

Comment: Hmm, I ran the following "SELECT eventID as ids, eventTitle as description, eventsTimestamp as timestamp, 'e' as status
                FROM   events
                WHERE  eventLocation = '1'
            ORDER BY timestamp DESC" and it simply says "Your SQL query has been executed successfully " but it didn't actually display any rows.

Comment: I meant the whole union query. And how about the returned result in MYSQL itself? No result returned? Could it be your data do not satisfy the query condition?

Comment: Oh, the whole thing? Only the results from my posts table are shown.

Comment: Running the query in MYSQL only return the post table? If it is so, did you double check the data in MYSQL table to make sure there is data that fit the condition?

Comment: You were right. I double checked my table and I accidentally wrote the eventslocations column incorrectly. It works perfectly now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A union/union all brings the rows together in one table, using the columns from the first table.  So, the result set has a PostsId, but no EventsId.

Perhaps you want a join, which will put the columns side-by-side.  Perhaps you want to run this as two separate queries.

Here is the example:

```
$sql = "select *
        from (SELECT postsID as postsID, postsSubject AS postsSubject, postsTimestamp AS timestamp
                FROM   posts
                WHERE  postsCategory = '$id') p
            cross join
                (SELECT eventID as eventID, eventTitle as eventTitle, eventsTimestamp as timestamp
                FROM   events
                WHERE  eventLocation = '$id') e
            ORDER BY postsTimeStamp DESC"
```

Do note that this is producing a cartesian product.  So, if there are more rows from one of the tables, then you will get a proliferation of rows.

Comment: How can I do a join as two separate queries? Can you please show me using the info above?